# JPA Annotation Error with OneToOne and composite primary key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-mvc, annotations

I have this relation:

```
+------------------+    +----------------+    +----------+
| TTR_AUT          |    | TTR_ANO_ESCALA |    | TTR_POA  |
+------------------+    +----------------+    +----------+
|#ID_ESCAL         |    |#ID_ESCAL       |    |#ID_ESCAL |
|#ANO              |----|#ANO            |----|#ANO      |
|#MES              |    | NOMBRE         |    |#MES      |
| OBSERVACIONES    |    +----------------+    | VALOR    |
+------------------+                          +----------+
```

TTR_AUT and TTR_POA have a oneToOne relation. And now I wont to get an object Aut with VALOR from POA. With the next entities:

**Entity Aut.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TTR_AUT")
public class Aut implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private AutPK id;

    @Column(name="OBSERVACIONES")
    private String observaciones;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinTable(name="TTR_POA",
        joinColumns = {
          @JoinColumn(name="ANO", insertable=false, updatable=false, referencedColumnName="ANO"),
          @JoinColumn(name="ID_ESCAL", insertable=false, updatable=false, referencedColumnName="ID_ESCAL"),
          @JoinColumn(name="MES", insertable=false, updatable=false, referencedColumnName="MES")          
        },
        inverseJoinColumns = {
          @JoinColumn(name="ANO", insertable=false, updatable=false, referencedColumnName="ANO"),
          @JoinColumn(name="ID_ESCAL", insertable=false, updatable=false, referencedColumnName="ID_ESCAL"),
          @JoinColumn(name="MES", insertable=false, updatable=false, referencedColumnName="MES")
        }     
      )
    private Poa poa;

    public Aut() {
    }

    //GETTERS AND SETTERS
}
```

**Entity AutPK.java**

```
@Embeddable
public class AutPK implements Serializable {
    //default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name="ID_ESCAL", unique=true, nullable=false, precision=22)
    private Long idEscal;

    @Column(name="ANO", unique=true, nullable=false, precision=22)
    private Long ano;

    @Column(name="MES", unique=true, nullable=false, precision=22)
    private Long mes;

    public AutPK() {
    }

    //GETTERS AND SETTERS
}
```

**Entity Poa.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TTR_POA")
public class Poa implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private PoaPK id;

    @Column(name="VALOR", precision=22)
    private BigDecimal valor;

    public Poa() {
    }

    //GETTERS AND SETTERS
}
```

**Entity PoaPK.java**

```
@Embeddable
public class PoaPK implements Serializable {
    //default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name="ID_ESCAL", unique=true, nullable=false, precision=22)
    private Long idEscal;

    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false, precision=22)
    private Long ano;

    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false, precision=22)
    private Long mes;

    public PoaPK() {
    }

    //GETTERS AND SETTERS
}
```

When I get the object Poa, it throws this error:

```
]] Root cause of ServletException.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class es.model.entities.Poa. Expected: class es.model.entities.PoaPK, got class es.model.entities.AutPK
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:314)
    at es.model.entities.dao.impl.AutDAOImpl.getAutDeterminada(AutDAOImpl.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class es.model.entities.Poa. Expected: class es.model.entities.PoaPK, got class es.model.entities.AutPK
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1079)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1006)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:613)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:441)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

***What's the problem/error?***

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason is your embeddable classes are same. I didnt see any difference between PoaPK and AutPK, what about if you just use same embeddable class for all? If this doesnt work also you can try [composite ID](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/os-hibernatejpa/index.html)

Comment: thanks! I have tried using a embeddable class for both and I get the error ORA-00918.With composite ID it works, but I couldn change this for boss mandates

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need define different serialVersionUID for PoaPK and AutPK.
Change serialVersionUID  of PoaPK to 2 or any other number other than 1.